# How to get spark executor logs from spark history server? (spark on mesos client mode)

Tags: apache-spark

We are running  spark on mesos client mode.
We have also spark history server.
Spark log events can be seen fine in spark history server.

But how we can get the spark executor logs from spark ui or spark history server?

Comment: Go to `Executors` tabs on shs - there is a link to every executor log file.

Comment: Jep jep, that's the place where I have checked these.

Comment: On mesos client mode executor logs won't appear there.

Comment: We have tried also without mesos, i.e. using spark cluster mode -- in that case executor logs can be found.

Comment: Is it so that executor logs can't be get when we have spark on mesos, client mode?

Comment: I don't have any experience with mesos, you should add that to your question.